# Trouble querying documents using CosmosDB SDK V3

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to update a document in my CosmosDB so I want to find the id of the existing document using the following query

```
string seasonDocumentId = null;

            FeedIterator setIterator = container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(
                "SELECT * FROM c where c.brand = 'hm' and c.DocumentType = 'Seasons'",
               requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
               {
                   PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("hm"),
                   MaxConcurrency = 1,
                   MaxItemCount = 1
               });

            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                using (ResponseMessage response = await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.Content))
                    using (JsonTextReader jtr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
                    {
                        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
                        SeasonInformation seasons = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<SeasonInformation>(jtr);
                        seasonDocumentId = seasons.id;
                        int i = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is that I always get NULL value for seasonDocumentId even though I know the actual query is correct and returns value if I use the Data Explorer to run the query so I must be missing something in the stream conversions but I cannot put my finger on what I am doing wrong.

Model looks like this

```
class SeasonInformation
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("brand")]
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string IntegrationSource { get; set; }
        public string DocumentType { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedDateUtc { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public JObject OriginalData { get; set; }
    }
```

Actual document in CosmosDB looks like this

```
{
    "id": "f05182d2-0a18-4cc4-b2df-585ad0464abb",
    "brand": "hm",
    "IntegrationSource": "HAPI",
    "DocumentType": "Seasons",
    "UpdatedDate": "3/12/2019 20:02:42",
    "UpdatedDateUtc": "2019-12-03T13:02:42.01Z",
    "UpdatedBy": "HAPI_HM_Seasons",
    "OriginalData": {
        "corporateBrandId": 0,
        "current": "201910"
    },
    "_rid": "xxx==",
    "_self": "dbs/HwVmAA==/colls/xxx=/docs/xxx==/",
    "_etag": "\"3e00bdf8-xxx-0c00-xxx-5de65cef0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 15753xxxx78159
}
```

Comment: PartitionKey is /brand and the value is hm, I tried hm, /brand and brand as the partitionkey value and it all fails with the same result I,e null

Comment: ok but it still dont work, seasons.id is still null

Comment: What if you tried to deserialize into a `dynamic` - does anything come back? Also, you were correct with the `'hm'` being your partition key - I wasn't sure earlier based on the question but you have clarified.

Comment: Yes if I do dynamic I can see the document in the debugger

Comment: no its DocumentType I am comparing the others though to see there must be a mismatch

Comment: It would seem like there is an issue with the deserialization then? Is `id` actually lowercase? Do you have any missing properties on your model?

Comment: Adding them to the question in case I am going in blind so you can see

Comment: Is it because the Cosmos stuff added below in the document? NO I tried specify each property in the SELECT but still no hit

Comment: You don't need to deserialize the object if you pass the type of the object you expecting like ```container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator<MyObject>...```

Comment: So it is better approach if you create a class of type of your document.

Comment: I have a class which matches my document exactly dont I ? I just added it into the question, but when I try add the type as in your comment it tells the generic method cannot have a type

Comment: Before you try to assign `seasons.id`, is `seasons` a hydrated object? You could try to slap on the `[JsonProperty]` attributes on all of your properties for explicit mapping

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with the hydrated object ? what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implement a simple console app for you and it could get id successfully for you , try the code below :

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace cosmosDBSDKV3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dbName = "<db name>";
            var containerName = "<container name>";

            CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("<cosmos db url>", "<key here>");
            Database database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
            Container container = database.GetContainer(containerName);

            ItemFeed(container).GetAwaiter().GetResult();


            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task ItemFeed(Container container)
        {
            FeedIterator<SeasonInformation> setIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<SeasonInformation>(
                "SELECT * FROM c where c.brand = 'hm' and c.DocumentType = 'Seasons'",
               requestOptions: new QueryRequestOptions()
               {
                   PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("hm"),
                   MaxConcurrency = 1,
                   MaxItemCount = 1
               });

            List<SeasonInformation> seasonInformations = new List<SeasonInformation>();

            // SQL

            while (setIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                int count = 0;
                foreach (SeasonInformation item in await setIterator.ReadNextAsync())
                {
                    count++;
                    seasonInformations.Add(item);
                }
            }

            foreach (SeasonInformation item in seasonInformations) {
                Console.WriteLine(item.id);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Brand);
            }



        }

        class SeasonInformation
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("brand")]
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public string IntegrationSource { get; set; }
            public string DocumentType { get; set; }
            public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
            public string UpdatedDateUtc { get; set; }
            public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
            public JObject OriginalData { get; set; }
        }
    }

}
```

In my cosmos db , this is my query result :
[image]

Code result :
[image]

Hope it helps .